# How to save model when using pytorch lightning and huggingface transformer?

Tags: pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

I am using huggingface with Pytorch lightning and and I am saving the model with Model_checkpoint method. It saves the file as .ckpt. I want to load the model using huggingface method .from_pretrained(), but I would get the warning the all of the layers are reinitialized (I renamed my file to pytorch_model.bin) . Any idea how to correctly save the model in order to be re-used using the .from_pretrained() methods.

Answer (score 0):

call trainer.save_checkpoint("path/to/save/model.ckpt"). This will save your model in a Hugging Face compatible format with the extension .ckpt.

```
import torch
    from transformers import AutoModel
    
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)

model = MyModel()

trainer.save_checkpoint("path/to/save/model.ckpt")

 from_pretrained method
loaded_model = MyModel()`
loaded_model.model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("path/to/save/model")
```

Comment: Does this work with pytroch-lightning? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that use the python class [PyTorchModelHubMixin](https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface_hub/v0.16.3/en/package_reference/mixins#huggingface_hub.PyTorchModelHubMixin) in your model class as follow:

```py
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module, PyTorchModelHubMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
```

It will give you the function `push_to_hub` to publish your model :

```py
model = MyModel()

# train your model 

model.push_to_hub("myaccount/mymodel")

# to load it 

model.from_pretrained("myaccount/mymodel")
```

A video is also available here : https://youtu.be/ENF7DqJEkIQ